# Is there a way to write a custom cumulative aggregate function with groupby clause for pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate-functions

Here's my dataframe

```
+--------+-------------+----------+---------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|        | Customer ID | Quantity | Invoice Value |       Date | InvoiceDate | UnitPrice |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|    0   |   500249347 |      0.0 |         0.000 | 2018-01-02 |  2018-01-02 |     0.000 |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|    1   |   500006647 |      1.0 |        33.715 | 2018-01-02 |  2018-01-02 |    33.715 |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|    2   |   500407469 |      1.0 |        33.715 | 2018-01-02 |  2018-01-02 |    33.715 |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|    3   |   500642846 |      0.0 |         0.000 | 2018-01-02 |  2018-01-02 |     0.000 |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|    4   |   500005450 |      1.0 |        33.715 | 2018-01-02 |  2018-01-02 |    33.715 |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|   ...  |         ... |      ... |           ... |        ... |         ... |       ... |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 429545 |   500717072 |      1.0 |        45.620 | 2019-03-31 |  2019-03-31 |    45.620 |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 429546 |   500105174 |      0.0 |         0.000 | 2019-03-31 |  2019-03-31 |     0.000 |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 429547 |   500069720 |      0.0 |         0.000 | 2019-03-31 |  2019-03-31 |     0.000 |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 429548 |   500105528 |      0.0 |         0.000 | 2019-03-31 |  2019-03-31 |     0.000 |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 429549 |   500732322 |      0.0 |         0.000 | 2019-03-31 |  2019-03-31 |     0.000 |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
```

I want to extract features (new columns) like **days since last visit for each customer** ( wrt.. snapshot date for each row), **last billed amount, last non-zero billed amount, quantity and days since last purchase** etc. can this be done using a some custom cumulative aggregate function or if there is a simpler way of doing it ?

Comment: Maybe you are searching for [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html)?

Comment: Days since last visit can be done by a groupby, and then a apply() of a custom function on the date column to calculate days between now and that date. Last billed ammount can be done by groupby and max() on the date column in combination with df.loc[]. This should give you enough to Google for on how to solve your problem. If you have any specific issue, let us know what you have tried so far and why it isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'customer_id': [13, 16, 13, 13, 16, 16, 13],
                   'Date': ['2018-01-02', '2019-03-31', '2019-03-31', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-02', '2019-04-31',
                            '2018-01-02'],
                   'Invoice_value': [920, 920, 920, 920, 921, 921, 921],
                   'Unit_price': [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]})

append_data = [df[(df['customer_id'] == ac)].sort_values(by=['Date']).iloc[-1] for ac in df.customer_id.unique()]
```

Answer (score 0):

For time since last visit, I figured something like this :

```
df['last_visited']=df.groupby('Customer ID')['Date'].diff()
```